# Question regarding notation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, notation, biophysics

In the paper [Inverse statistical problems: from the inverse Ising problem to data science](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01522) for equation (51), the authors state, "This yields equations which determine the values $m^{MF}_i$ of the magnetization parameters that minimize the KL divergence between the mean-field ansatz
and the Boltzmann distribution, namely the well-known
self-consistent equations
$$m^{MF}_i = \operatorname{th}(h_i + \sum_{j \neq i} J_{ij} m_j^{MF})"$$
Does the '$\operatorname{th}$' here simply mean some Gibbs type of distribution i.e. $e^{- \beta (.)}$ for some $\operatorname{th}(.)$?

Comment: Per Wikipedia: [*The abbreviations sh, ch, th, cth are also currently used, depending on personal preference.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! It makes sense now.